# MQTT with Android

Tags: java, android, mqtt, paho

I'm trying to publish a message via MQTT. So I created a blank Android app and added the Paho MQTT library to it.

This is the line of code I execute first:

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://192.168.178.34", "Foo");
```

This throws an "MqttException" which contains no message, no error code, no nothing. So currently I have no idea what's going wrong.

I also added the following permissions to my app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Can anyone give me a hint what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Any reason you are using the raw client and not the Android Client?

Comment: Are you using tls in the broker configuration?

Comment: Because its simpler and synchronous (which is what I need). I don't use TLS. Also the error occurs even before I call "connect".

Comment: Add the exception stack trace to the question then we can see exactly where it's been thrown from

Answer (score 0):

In the code, The activated class is the **[TCPNetworkModule](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/internal/TCPNetworkModule.java)** class which is using connect method of the socket class directly(see the start method of the class).

I think the exception might be the **NetworkOnMainThreadException** 
attempting to use blocking IO.

That's why we use **MqttAndroidClient** instead.